# Why did Beerus say "Say something." at the end of Episode 118 of Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

At the end of Episode 118 of Dragon Ball Super, just after Champa and Universe 6 is erased, Beerus says "Say something."

Could this mean that Champa will continue to live on in Beerus' mind? Or did they previously have a connection that allowed them to communicate telepathically?

Comment: He said say something to the announcer, because at such an emotional moment the character had enough screen time and decided the episode to be over.

Answer (score 5):

**Due to their brotherly bond, he wished to have heard some goodbye words.** Beerus deeply cares for Champa as does Champa for him. They are like siblings. They always fight, cause drama but at the end of the day they want the best for each other.

During the fight between the Namekians and Gohan & Picollo. Whiz was asking Beerus why he was silent for a while and is he worried that Champa's universe might be erased. Nobody knows Beerus like Whiz does, so if he asked that question then it implies that Beerus was genuinely worried about Champa.

Remember the episode of the tournament before this where Beerus's universe won from Champa's universe? They were awarded a wish with the universal Shenron. What did Beerus wish for? To restore the planet earth in Champa's universe, so that Champa could enjoy the good food as well. He could wish for selfish things or to strengthen his warriors or whatever else, but he did it so that his kid brother could be happy and enjoy the food as well. This indicates that Beerus cares about Champa the same way as an adult brother cares for his kid brother.

So back to the universal tournament; the stakes are high and while they enjoy fighting each other we can conclude that both want to win, but they don't want their brother to lose either. If anything Champa wishes deeply that if he doesn't win then his Brother Beerus should and vice versa.

At the final moment Champa called out to his big bro and would've probably said something but he isn't a fool. Due to his troubled face he resorted to making a funny face instead, indirectly telling Beerus to not worry and rather to focus on winning. Beerus on the other hand... wanted to hear some parting words. A "good bye!" or "good luck!" would have lifted his spirits a bit, but knowing Champa he didn't want to resort to a touching goodbye, so he acted accordingly to his behaviour. **Beerus wish to hear some final words was what made him say that.**

This is simply the bond of an elder brother losing his younger brother while both are aware that one is going to vanish... and at the moment of vanishing you would want to hear your brothers voice doesn't matter what it is. **This is more something emotional and sensitive rather than some beyond-human-level form of communication.** This was the feeling of losing someone close to you while being unable to do anything about it at all.

Off-topic; Vegeta was pretty pissed about it as well. And remember what Vegeta said to Cabba? He would win the tournament and wish Cabba's universe back so that Cabba could show him around in his universe. At the current episode and ending I think that Beerus has a similar feeling right now. He wished planet earth back for his brother previously. It is quite obvious what his next wish will be (if they are granted a wish at all).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this could be interpreted in many ways. I have an alternate answer than the one which has already been stated. I believe Beerus was talking to the narrator which happens in a lot of anime. This is because Beerus doesn't know what to say after what happened and asks the narrator to speak which is probably why we hear the narrator speak right after followed by Vegeta's interaction with Katopesla.

Beerus, a character who never shows emotion on screen, is feeling legitimate sadness for the first time on screen. He just lost his brother and is being focused on by the camera. Beerus obviously being conflicted with how he felt probably wanted to be left alone (audiences eyes off him) and out of the spotlight and as OP says thats why he says "say something" because he's telling the narrator to hurry it up. This might be considered as disrespect just because of its 4th wall breaking, I'd say it's more emotional. We have a character like Beerus who wants to be left alone and out of site due to the erasure of his brother, he wanted the episode to end because his brother had been erased.

[Gohan breaking the 4th wall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwdcvYc8flo)

[Vegeta breaking the 4th wall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGlk9arVKSs)

Comment: Did you mean by narrator the "referee" that announces when an universe/warrior has dropped out or the person that tells what happened during the previous/next episode of dragon ball super?

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up?  I have a hard time believing that in a serious episode they would break the 4th wall.

Comment: +Ravi Bechoe  I'm referring to the narrator who mentions right after Universe 2 and Universe 6 are erased. The person who usually narrates what happens at the start and end of the anime.  +Becuzz when Universe 2 was erased, it was as though they were addressing the audience towards the end from when they say "Formation"/ Maybe they were trying to say that Ribrianne is a popular character in Japan despite being hated in general.

Comment: Also, I can't remember which episode exactly, but there was an episode where one of the writers or show producer or someone appeared on the tournament of power stage and spoke to the audience regarding the tournament of power. Also, I really don't think this was a very serious episode as they managed to incorporate a lot of humor into it too. Like Caulifla chasing the Namekians in the end, Vados sitting with Universe 7 and Champa making the funny face at Beerus. I think this could be a different way to interpret what Beerus meant when he said that.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 When I say "serious episode" I mean something that isn't a joke episode, like the one with Arale.  Those kind of filler-ish type episodes where they are just having fun are where I would expect things like breaking the 4th wall.  In a more normal episode though, I wouldn't expect that at all.

Comment: @Becuzz I really feel it is because even right before Universe 2 was erased, the angel was upset and didn't use his staff anymore so Ribrianne wasn't talking to the rest of the people, it very much appeared as though Ribrianne was addressing the audience right before she was erased. Also, dragon ball is watched by a lot of kids and the other interpretations of "say something" mentioned here is just too much for a normal kid to understand. We even see the camera focussing on Beerus and then shifting immediately after with the narrator speaking after he said that.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 Ahh then I understood it correctly with what you meant about the narrator, but I don't recall a single episode where a character, in the dragon ball series, communicated with the narrator.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 I always interpreted Ribrianne (and the rest of U2's crew) talking to the camera as talking to the inhabitants of U2 before they got erased.  We see scenes where those people are watching the tournament and waving their glow sticks around.  (I know the angel wasn't shown to be using his staff, but it wouldn't be the first time Super had an animation mistake or that Toriyama / the rest of the writers forgot a detail.)  Your interpretation has some basis, but I think we will just have to agree to disagree here.

Comment: @RaviBechoe I've added a link to my answer showing Gohan breaking the fourth wall.

Comment: Thanks for providing samples, I will look it up after work in the manga and original japanese version. Some times the dub versions have been tampered with in order to make things a little bit more amusing. This was a common practise for implementing jokes and such during the 90s.

Answer (score 0):

Beerus had been silent the entire time champas universe started loosing aces as said by whiss. However when universe 6 was about to be deleted and champa called out to him; it looked as though he had decided to still stay silent until that moment his brother called out to him. Beerus looks out of the corner of his eyes to see his little brothers silly but somewhat content face at him during his own erasure and says TO HIMSELF, say something. As to imply to himself not to be silent suring his brothers erasure, to say something before you never see eachother again but wanst able to manage anything but that.

Answer (score 0):

Beerus said "say something" because he can speak with Champa through his mind. He doesn't believe that Champa is actually gone so he says "say something". But Champa can't answer because he is erased from existence.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Beerus was testing telepathically trying to speak to his brother to really see wether or not he's been erased. So when he says "say something", he's trying to communicate with his brother telepathically. Even tho they fought allot, they do love each other very much. Brothers just act that way.